# Big Query Create View with Repeated Record

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

We have a series of tables with schema that contains a repeated record, like follows:

```
[{
    name: "field1",
    type: "RECORD",
    mode: "REPEATED",
    fields: [{type: "STRING", name: "subfield1"}, {type: "INTEGER", name: "subfield2"}]
}]
```

when we create a view that include that repeated record field, we always get error:

```
Error in query string: Field field1 from table xxxxx is not a leaf field.
```

I understand that it might be better to use flatten, but all this field contains mostly different filters we want to test on and we have a lot of other non-repeated fields that would be difficult to manage if flattened.

It turned out that the problem is selecting the repeated record field from multiple tables (not in creating view). Is there an easy way to get around that?

Thanks

Comment: How does your select statement look like?

Comment: It looks like `Select field1 from (TABLE_QUERY(dataset, 'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, xxx)'))`

Comment: You need to explicitly type as field1.*

Comment: It turns out that doesn't work either: `Error in query string: 0.0 - 0.0: Wildcard pattern field1.* cannot be used to refer to fields in a union`

Comment: I think the two correlates, try without the table_query function first

Comment: Tried the following, still got the same error: `select field1.* from dataset1.table1, dataset1.table2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `SELECT field.* from t1, t2`  you'll get an error that the * cannot be used to refer fields in a union (as you've noticed above).

You can work around this by wrapping the union in an inner SELECT statement, as in `SELECT field.* from (SELECT * from t1, t2)`.

To give a concrete example, this works:

```
SELECT payload.pages.* 
FROM (
    SELECT *  
    FROM [publicdata:samples.github_nested],   
         [publicdata:samples.github_nested])
```